# C# How To Separate Login For Admin And User

Tags: c#, authentication

So basically Admin and User goes to different windows, here's the code

```
private void cmdEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtUsername.Text == "" && txtPassword.Text == "") //Error when all text box are not fill
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to fill Username and Password", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtUsername.Text == "") //Error when all text box are not fill
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to fill Username", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtPassword.Text == "") //Error when all text box are not fill
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to fill Password", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root";
                    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

                    MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from boardinghousedb.employee_table where username='" + this.txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + this.txtPassword.Text + "' ;", myConn);

                    MySqlDataReader myReader;

                    myConn.Open();
                    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    int count = 0;
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password . . . is Correct", "Confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                        this.Hide();
                        Menu mm = new Menu();
                        mm.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else if (count > 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and Password . . . Access Denied", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is Not Correct . . . Please try again", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        myConn.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }       
        }
```

but I don't know how, other tutorials talks about local database but I'm using MySQL[Here is the employee table, title=admin or user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Ehd9.png)

Comment: For starters, this code is wide open to SQL injection.  You're going to want to look into parameterized queries.  Aside form that, it's not really clear to me what you're asking.  In what way is this code not working?  What's the problem?

Comment: It seems I can log into *any* of your accounts, as long as my password is `PLAIN WRONG' UNION SELECT * from boardinghousedb.employee_table LIMIT 1; --`

Comment: your check in regards to `if count ==1` is in correct.. if you are checking for duplicates this is still incorrect.. you need to structure your database so that you have Id's for users and admins and structure your query to return that .. then in your query if the user name and password are correct then check if they try to access Admin when they should be a user then display a message and learn how to use the `return` key word after checking messages.. if you have blank user and password you need to showmessage and immediately `return` meaning exit that method..

Comment: you need to re-work some of your logic..

Comment: the code is working fine . .It's just that I Admin and Employee goes to different windows when login . .How can I do that ? . ."title" is the name of the attribute in the database for Admin or Employee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems with your code.

1. you should create unique constraint in your database to avoid users with duplicate usernames
2. You should keep your passwords hashed, rather than in plain text. This way, if someone gets to your database, he will still not be able to read passwords.
3. You should use SQL Parametrzided queries to avoid SQL Injection.
   Your query is prone to SQL Injection. SQL Injection is a way of injecting SQL Commands in to your query. Some user could write `someName' OR 1=1--` in your username textbox, and your query would translate as `select * from boardinghousedb.employee_table where username='someName' OR 1=1--`. Note the `--` in the end, which makes rest of the query commented out. You can read more at [this](http://securityidiots.com/Web-Pentest/SQL-Injection/bypass-login-using-sql-injection.html) link. If you are allowed, i suggest you to look in to the EntityFramework. It's really powerful tool for querying your database.
4. Use `finally` block after catch to close your db connections.

Related to your question, if you want to distinguish admin from user, you need to introduce some kind of role, or at least bool value where you state `IsAdmin` for that user.

You can then place your code to a separate function/functions/classes, depending on your needs, and query users with `WHERE Role='Admin'` or similar.

For an example

```
public bool IsValidLogin(string username, string password);
```

or

```
public bool IsValieLoginForAdmin(string username, string password);
```

or any other implementation you like.

And then re-use it in a following way:

```
private void cmdEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if(IsValidLogin("username", "password"))

     //or

     if(IsValidLoginForAdmin("username", "password"))

//do something

}
```

**EDIT:**

You could also introduce new column to your table, caled `UserRole`. For the simplicity, I will just modify your code as it is, and you can re-factor it as you learn.

```
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from boardinghousedb.employee_table where username='" + this.txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + this.txtPassword.Text + "' ;", myConn);

                    MySqlDataReader myReader;

                    myConn.Open();
                    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    int count = 0;
                    string userRole = string.Empty;
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                        userRole = myReader["UserRole"].ToString();
                    }
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password . . . is Correct", "Confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                        this.Hide();
                        if(userRole =="Admin")
                        //show admin window
                        else
                        //show user window
                        Menu mm = new Menu();
                        mm.ShowDialog();
                    }
```

Comment: I'm still a student, I don't know if our school is behind , but to be honest what you are saying is all new to me . . I don't even know what SQL Injection means :(

Comment: @LeeJun I've added more info about sql injection in my answer

Comment: @LeeJun, please check my EDIT for your solution.

Comment: @LeeJun no problem. Please mark answer as solution if helped you.

Comment: ofcourse but I don't know how, this is my 2nd question here, I really don't know how to mark your answer as the solution

Comment: @LeeJun on the place where you up vote for answer, you have a small check-mark under it. Just click on it.

Comment: Done. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

```
MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from boardinghousedb.employee_table where username='" + this.txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + this.txtPassword.Text + "' ;", myConn);

                MySqlDataReader myReader;

                myConn.Open();
                myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                int count = 0;
                string userRole = string.Empty;
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    count = count + 1;
                    userRole = myReader["UserRole"].ToString();
                }
                if (count == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Username and Password . . . is Correct", "Confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    this.Hide();
                    if(userRole =="Admin")
                    //show admin window
                    else
                    //show user window
                    Menu mm = new Menu();
                    mm.ShowDialog();
                }

              else if (count > 1)
              { MessageBox.Show("Duplicate User And Password"); }
             else
                 MessageBox.Show("Username and Password Incorrect", "Login Error:");
               myConn.Close();
        }
```

Comment: This is quite a lot of code to present without any explanation. Adding some comments would greatly increase the long-term usefulness of your answer.

Answer (score -2):

your code

```
            if (txtUsername.Text == "" && txtPassword.Text == "") //Error when all text box are not fill
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to fill Username and Password", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtUsername.Text == "") //Error when all text box are not fill
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to fill Username", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtPassword.Text == "") //Error when all text box are not fill
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Unable to fill Password", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            else
            {
                try
                {
                    string myConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root";
                    MySqlConnection myConn = new MySqlConnection(myConnection);

                    MySqlCommand SelectCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from boardinghousedb.employee_table where username='" + this.txtUsername.Text + "' and password='" + this.txtPassword.Text + "' ;", myConn);

                    MySqlDataReader myReader;

                    myConn.Open();
                    myReader = SelectCommand.ExecuteReader();
                    int count = 0;
                    while (myReader.Read())
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }
                    if (count == 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password . . . is Correct", "Confirmation Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                        this.Hide();
                        Menu mm = new Menu();
                        mm.ShowDialog();
                    }
                    else if (count > 1)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and Password . . . Access Denied", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Username and Password is Not Correct . . . Please try again", "Error Message!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        myConn.Close();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
```

this code has missing its return type the error says